# Cordova 6.1.0 SplashScreen Not Working

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, splash-screen

config.xml has following lines:

```
<preference name="SplashScreen" value="screen"/>
<preference name="SplashScreenDelay" value="3000"/>
```

Cordova splash screen plugin is also installed. splash.png is in resources fodler and I have generated splash images using "ionic resources --splash" command as well. Still not able to see splash screen while running app through "ionic serve" command.

Please suggest if there is anything else need to be done here.

Answer (score 0):

The Ionic SplashScreen will only work when you are running the app on an actual device or on an emulator. I believe it will also show in the `Ionic View App` provided by Ionic to preview apps. The issue here is you're trying to use Cordova Native Plugins in a web browser.

Your Options;
 1. Build .apk and run on device/Emulator
 2. Upload your app to Ionic cloud by doing `$ ionic upload` and then viewing your app throught he Ionic View App.